# Append .sql file to existing database

Tags: mysql

I need to export rows from one database (db1) and append them in another database (db2). Basically it is a kind of appending data from operational database db1 into archive database db2, once a month.

I'm trying to use mysqldump to create partial dump file from db1 and then import that dump by appending data into db2 but facing problems. I tried adding --skip-add-drop-table to mysqldump to avoid dropping tables at import with

```
mysql -u user -p db2 < db1_partial_dump.sql
```

Also consider important: there are new tables in db1 from time to time. What would need to be done is to append rows to existing tables, and create new table if does not exist. To achieve that I tried to replace  CREATE TABLE in sql dump by

```
sed -i 's/CREATE TABLE/CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS/g' db1_partial_dump.sql
```

however I have error "ERROR 1062 (23000) at line 136: Duplicate entry '809' for key 'PRIMARY'".

I don't know how to proceed from here nor if it is possible at all to do such appending. Please advise.

Comment: Maybe [--insert-ignore](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_insert-ignore) could help?

Comment: `INSERT IGNORE` will cause to loss updated rows data. If row already exists on archive DB but has changed on operation DB this changes will not stored in archive